# Can ServiceStack services contain multiple methods?

Tags: c#, api, rest, soa, servicestack

Environment is Visual Studio 2012, ServiceStack, ASP.NET Web Application Project (followed https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice)

Looking through some of the classes in ServiceStack.Examples, I noticed that most of the services contain only one method. Either some override on `Execute()` or, if a REST service, some override of `OnPost/Get/Put/Delete()`.

How should I approach making a full API set, if I have tens of functions I need implemented `RegisterUser()`, `RemoveUser()`, `AddFriend()`, `RemoveFriend()` ... One service per method?

```
public RegisterUserService : IService<User> { public object Execute(User> dto) { ... } }
public RemoveUserService : IService<User> { public object Execute(User> dto) { ... } }
public AddFriendService : IService<Friend> { public object Execute(Friend dto) { ... } }
public RemoveFriendService: IService<RequestDTO4> { public object Execute(Friend dto) { ... } }
```

I'm pretty lost on how to begin implementing a full API set. I've read the [first](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice) and [second](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Your-first-webservice-explained) wiki page on 'Creating your first webservice', which I've copied to make 1 service method. But now I want to make 10 or 40 service methods and I'm not sure how to do that.

I noticed that implementing from `IRestService<T>` allows you up to 4 methods instead of the one `Execute()` method, simply because each method corresponds to a different HTTP verb. So is there something like that I could write? Basically something like:

```
public MyService : IService/IRestService/ServiceBase?<User>
{
     public object AddUser(User user) { }
     public object RemoveUser(User user) { }
     public object ModifyUser(User user) { }
}
```

Just looking for something that doesn't necessarily have to contain all methods in one service class, but as many as reasonably possible ... do I really have to create 1 service for each service method?

Note on pursuing a strictly RESTful architecture: I only read up a little on REST, but it seems like I'd have to strictly follow rules like: treat everything as a resource even if you have to re-design your models, no verbs in the URL names (/Friends, not /GetFriends because REST gives you OnGet(), OnPost(), OnPut(), and OnDelete() ... basically I'm interested in the easiest, quickest, and most painless way of implementing a a few dozen service methods. It's a personal project, so the requirements won't vary too much.

Thanks in advance for guiding me through this first step.

EDIT: Just saw this related question: [How to send commands using ServiceStack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060919/how-to-send-commands-using-servicestack?rq=1)

Mythz said there's no "ServiceStack way" to design. The guy's question is pretty much like mine. I'm wondering how to stack a lot of service methods in a service.

EDIT 2: Just saw [Need help on servicestack implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007232/need-help-on-servicestack-implementation), and [Separate or combined ServiceStack services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415972/separate-or-combined-servicestack-services?rq=1).

I just tested the code below successfully with working routes:

```
[Route("/registerUser/setEmail/{Email}")]
[Route("/registerUser/setPassword/{Password}")]
[Route("/registerUser/setPhoneNumber/{PhoneNumber}")]
[Route("/lalal2395823")]
[Route("/test3234/test23423511")]
public class RegisterUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

But **what I'd like is for each `[Route("path")]` to go to a *different* method**, instead of having them all parsed in `Execute()` and having to parse which string isn't null or empty.

---

### My Solution

I decided to take Rickard's advice and make a proper REST API, because it seems simpler and cleaner in the end.

This is now my class using [the new ServiceStack API (new as of 9/24/12)](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-API):

```
using UserModel = Project.Model.Entities.User;

[Route("/User", "POST")]
[Route("/User/{FirstName}", "POST")]
[Route("/User/{FirstName}/{LastName}", "POST")]
[Route("/User/{FirstName}/{LastName}/{Nickname}", "POST")]
[Route("/User/{FirstName}/{LastName}/{Nickname}/{PhoneNumber}", "POST")]
[Route("/User/{FirstName}/{LastName}/{Nickname}/{PhoneNumber}/{Email}", "POST")]
public class CreateUser : IReturn<UserModel>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class CreateUserService : Service
{
   public object Post(CreateUser request)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var session = FluentNHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    var user = new UserModel()
                    {
                        FirstName = request.FirstName,
                        LastName = request.LastName,
                        Nickname = request.Nickname,
                        PhoneNumber = request.PhoneNumber,
                        Email = request.Email,
                        Password = request.Password,
                    };
                    session.SaveOrUpdate(user);
                    transaction.Commit();

                    return user;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although it is permitted, I don't think it is a good idea to decorate your DTO with routes. Probably better to register your routes in AppHost.

Comment: @epitka Why do you think it's not a good idea? On contrary, I think it's great idea to see what service is hosted where when you are looking at it.

Comment: I totally agree with @epitka (even though my answer below uses the attribute pattern). Simply separating concerns makes this a no-brainer . When I write unit tests for my routes they should not have anything to do with the DTO and vice versa simply because it makes it harder to change and maintain.

Comment: Exactly, single responsibility principle. DTO=Data Transfer Object, not Route Definition Object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the HTTP way you have to turn your way of thinking upside down. You need to think in terms of resources, i.e. users, friends, etc. Using HTTP you already have a finite set of methods, namely Get, Put, Post, and Delete.

Hence, the service API design could look like this:

```
RegisterUser() => POST /users
RemoveUser() => DELETE /users/{userid}
AddFriend() => POST /users/{userid}/friends
RemoveFriend() => DELETE /users/{userid}/friends/{friendid}
ModifyUser() => PUT /users/{userid}
```

etc.

To implement for example RemoveFriend in ServiceStack you could do like this:

```
public class UserFriendService : RestServiceBase<UserFriendRequest>
{
    public override object OnPost(UserFriendRequest request)
    {
        // pseudo code 
        var user = GetUser(request.UserId);
        var friend = GetUser(request.FriendId); // FriendId is a field in the HTTP body
        user.Friends.Add(friend);
        return HttpResult.Status201Created(user, ...);
    }
    //...
}

[Route("/users/{userId}/friends")]
public class UserFriendRequest
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FriendId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm beginning to accept the REST standard as the clearest and simplest way. Thanks for the thorough answer. One question: Isn't it kind of redundant to have a UserFriendRequest class, but also have a Model\Entities\User.cs and Model\Entities.Friend.cs. Is there any way I can re-use that? <- And I think there's some common name to describe this redundancy - what's the technical term so I can read more about it?

Comment: well, I don't think so. Think of the UserFriendRequest as a request DTO, a contract which specifically describes what kind of input that resource accepts. I wouldn't want to expose my entire User database model in this case.

Comment: there will also be many more request DTOs like UserRequest, FriendRequest etc. Keep in mind that the service request DTO is not the same as the response, e.g. what you return. As you've noticed ServiceStack returns object which let you return what ever object you like, e.g. List<User> in the GET /users case

Comment: Thanks for the jumpstart. I've created a few classes and everything seems well.

Comment: Hey @Rickard great advice! You might also be interested in ServiceStack's new API Design which now makes it a lot easier to handle multiple Request DTOs in the same service :) https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-API

Answer (score 11):

This is now a lot simpler with [ServiceStack's new API Design](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-API) released in (v3.9.15+).

@Rickard makes a lot of good points on how to re-structure your service so it's more REST-ful which is now easier to achieve with ServiceStack's new API which is now less restrictive and more flexible where the same service can handle multiple different Request DTOs and you're no longer restricted in the Response Type you can return.

Comment: This is amazing; many thanks for your contributions to ServiceStack.