# ServiceStack URLs for related services

Tags: odata, servicestack

With [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net), I'm looking for ways to access related services by composing the URLs in a manner similar to OData.

An [OData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478141.aspx) example would be a URL like

```
http://localhost:8080/owind.svc/Categories(2)/Products
```

This would find all the Products related to Category 2.

An equivalent example with ServiceStack seems to be that you would create a Request DTO for a ProductService and set up Routes something like this:

```
[Route("/Products")]
[Route("/Products/{Id}")]
[Route("/Categories/{Category}/Products")]
public class Products
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

(Ignore the separations of concerns issues mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549981/can-servicestack-services-contain-multiple-methods), the above attributes at least give a clear idea what I'm asking.)

And then in the ProductService you'd support finding Products either via the primary or foreign key. I see something along these lines used in the Northwind.ServiceModel.Operations.Orders class of the ServiceStack.Northwind.ServiceModel sample project.

So I'm wondering, is this the best and most scalable way that exists to do this sort of thing in ServiceStack, or is there some shortcut I'm missing? Thinking on a scale of creating services supporting hundreds of tables, if there existed some sort of shortcut, and if it didn't come with strings attached, it could be helpful.

I can imagine a system where you could automatically generate routes based on anything in a DTO, though you'd need to do some mapping from DTO property name (usually singular) to route (often plural).

No idea if it would be conceivable to carry this beyond one level either...for example

```
.../Employee/1/Orders/Customers
```

which would get you every Customer who has had an Order with Employee #1. The notion of implementing this manually on a large scale seems prohibitive. Not sure if there are SOA arguments to be made for or against, but that would be nice to know as well.

Just to be clear, there should be no assumption of the underlying data store or access libraries.

Comment: In depth and interesting discussion of some of the associated issues over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577938/odata-with-servicestack. Alex James also turns up in the comments with some interesting links that might be helpful if you head down this road.